# Copy a part of cell to the following cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
              match        0
GRMN 10300      0      GRMN 10200
GRMN 10300      1           10201
```

I want to have it as follows:

```
              match        0
GRMN 10300      0      GRMN 10200
GRMN 10300      1      GRMN 10201
```

The first and the second column are my index.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you just want to fill forward the GRMN since the column 'match' is 1? Maybe give some more description of what you want and a more detailed example please

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need:

- [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for creating 2 columns
- [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) empty spaces to `NaN`
- concanecate both columns to one by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `join`

```
df1 = df['0'].str.extract('(^[a-zA-z]*)\s*(\d+)$', expand=True)
print (df1)
               0      1
GRMN 10300  GRMN  10200
     10300        10201

df['0'] = df1.replace('',np.nan).ffill().apply(' '.join, axis=1)
print (df)
            match           0
GRMN 10300      0  GRMN 10200
     10300      1  GRMN 10201
```